# Why Companion object is not accessible from Java code?

Tags: java, kotlin, companion-object, kotlin-companion

As we know Kotlin and Java are inter-operable. When I try to access Java static variable inside Kotlin code it works, but when I try to access companion object in Java, it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add **JvmStatic** annotation

```
companion object{
    @JvmStatic
    val x=10
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are no statics in Kotlin per se.

Properties of the companion object can be accessed in Java by explicitly referring to the `Companion` instance:

```kotlin
class MyKotlinClass {
    companion object {
        val someProperty = 42
    }
}
```

From Java:

```java
int someProperty = MyKotlinClass.Companion.getSomeProperty();
```

---

You can also force Kotlin to output bytecode with static members (for Java) by using a JVM-specific annotation:

```kotlin
class MyKotlinClass {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        val someProperty = 42
    }
}
```

From Java:

```java
int someProperty = MyKotlinClass.getSomeProperty();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `Companion` explicitly. Java:

```
    MyFragment newFragment = MyFragment.Companion.newInstance();
```

That's because companion's methods are NOT static. The companion is static, but its methods are regular, instance methods.